# "Scaffolding failed. Could not load information for project..." in .NET 6 Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0

I got this message when trying to create an API Controller.
I did seperate API project referrence to DBContext and entities in another class library.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mxjt.png)

I have tried the same project with .NET 5, it's working well but not .NET 6.
Please help me!

Comment: Same problem. Seems like there is a bug.

Comment: Can you provide the version of VS2022?

Comment: @XinranShen Visual Studio Community 2022 17.3.4

Answer (score 2):

Trevoir Williams from Udemy said: Versions 6.0.8 and 6.0.9 you can reduce the version of the EntityFrameworkCore* libraries to 6.0.7 in project file
[image: Project File]

Or change EntityFrameworkCore* version in NuGet package manager
[image: Nuget package manager]

Again, all this information and images I get from Trevoir Williams. I think this issue will be solved quickly. In this time, this is the fast way for everyone love .NET 6.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and solved updating:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore to 6.0.9

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools to 6.0.9

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design to 6.0.10
```